# Why is custom HandleError attribute called with ExceptionHandled=true in MVC4 website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In an MVC4 website the following custom HandleError attribute is registered

```
public class JHSHandleErrorAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.ExceptionHandled || !filterContext.HttpContext.IsCustomErrorEnabled)
        {
            return;
        }

       //Handler for non-500 errors
        if (new HttpException(null, filterContext.Exception).GetHttpCode() != 500)
        {
            return;
        }
     ...
```

in Global.asax like this

```
protected static void RegisterMVCGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
  //Add HandleError attribute as default for all controller exceptions
  filters.Add(new JHS.Web.Mvc.JHSHandleErrorAttribute
    {
      View = "Error/general"
    }, 1);

  filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute(), 2);

}
```

The custom HandleError attribute is called when an exception occurs and the `filterContext.ExceptionHandled=true` resulting in the standard error page to be displayed.

However, if the custom HandleError attribute is added to an individual action like this, the `filterContext.Exceptionhandled=false` and the rest of the method is executed resulting in the  custom error view being displayed.

```
[JHS.Web.Mvc.JHSHandleError(View="Error/general")]
public ActionResult Index()
{

  throw new ArgumentNullException("test");
...
```

Why is the `filterContext.ExceptionHandled=true the custom view displayed when the custom error attribute is registered at the global level?

Comment: Could You somehow edit Your post so that the question makes sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of filter execution is described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513%28VS.98%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filterscope%28v=vs.98%29.aspx).
That still stands for MVC 4.

Basically filter registered on Global level (`HandleErrorAttribute`) gets executed before your custom filter defined on Action level.

This might seem strange - but that's how it is.